# How to use .toggle() to show a div as table

Tags: jquery, css

I have a hidden div that should be displayed as a `table` instead of `block`. The default behavior of toggle is to show an initially hidden (`display: none;`) object as a `block` (`display: block;`). But I want to display it as a table (`display: table;`) instead (see [this](http://www.senktec.com/2014/01/using-css-display-table-cell-for-columns/) to understand why that could be useful if you doubt my sanity). Is that possible?

I could initialize the object as a table and then hide it in the ready-function. But that would render the object visible to the user for some microseconds before hidden and perceived as an ugly flickering.

The last option is maybe to use something like `.css('display', 'table')`, but toggle would be nicer and cleaner if it could be used.

An example:

```
<div id="hidden_table" style="display: none;">                             
  <div style="display: table-row;">                                        
    <div style="display: table-cell;">Cell 1</div>                         
    <div style="display: table-cell;">Cell 2</div>                         
  </div>                                                                   
  <div style="display: table-row;">                                        
    <div style="display: table-cell;">Cell 3</div>                         
    <div style="display: table-cell;">Cell 4</div>                         
  </div>                                                                   
</div>                                                                     
<a onclick='jQuery("#hidden_table").toggle();'>Click Me</a>
```

In this example the display-property would be set to `block` when "Click Me" is hit. But I would like it to be set to table. And of course I know this could be achieved by crafting some custom code as I wrote earlier. But I want to know if there is some trick with `.toggle()` that I am missing?

Comment: What is the actual problem? How to use `display: table` in the toggle, how to avoid the 'flicker,' how to animate between states..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the solution myself**:

**1.** When `.toggle()` is called to **hide** an element it will update the elements inline style display property (adding it if not defined) to `none`. So:

```
<div id="my_test">Foo</div>
<script>jQuery("#my_test").toggle();</script>
```

would result in:

```
<div id="my_test" style="display: none;">Foo</div>
```

**2.** When `.toggle()` is called to **show** an element it will also update the elements inline style display property (adding it if not defined). But this time it will copy the display-property from a definition of lower priority, defaulting to `block` if no lower-priority definition could be found. So if we add an inline stylesheet to the original example it could look like this:

```
<style>                                                                    
  #hidden_table {display: table; }                                         
</style>                                                                   
<div id="hidden_table" style="display: none;">                             
  <div style="display: table-row;">                                        
    <div style="display: table-cell;">Cell 1</div>                         
    <div style="display: table-cell;">Cell 2</div>                         
  </div>                                                                   
  <div style="display: table-row;">                                        
    <div style="display: table-cell;">Cell 3</div>                         
    <div style="display: table-cell;">Cell 4</div>                         
  </div>                                                                   
</div>
<a onclick='jQuery("#hidden_table").toggle();'>Click Me</a>
```

And when "Click Me" is hit now the inline display property would be copied from the internal stylesheet resulting in:

```
...
<div id="hidden_table" style="display: table;">
...
```

---

**And this is exactly what I was asking for!** Do this:

1. Add `style="display: none;"` to the element.
2. Set the desired display-property in an inline/file css-definition for the element.

Answer (score 4):

Write a toggler on your own like,

```
function toggleDisplay(element) {
  var display = element.css('display');
  element.css('display',(display==="table")?"none":"table");
}
```

And use it by,

```
toggleDisplay($('#element'));
```

Comment: the problem is he may need the animated effect by `toggle`, can this animate the show/hide state?

Comment: @KingKing I just answered this way because OP was talking about `.css('display', 'table')` ..! Am i right .?

Comment: no if so I doubt that the OP already knows about this, so this answer may be exactly what he knows (the last option).

Comment: @KingKing i too think so, but what the OP is exactly looking for is, a build in Jquery function which should do the job that he's asking for. But apparently it is not available..

Comment: I was not aiming for the animation or any other fancy thing in toggle at the moment, but just cleaner code. But the animation thing is defiantly a thing to consider.
As I wrote in the Q (and as @c-link writes) and as [the doc](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) explains the initial state is saved  on hide and then reused when showing the element. Hence my Q: It would/should be possible to send the display-property to use to `.toggle()` as a param in the call, why not?

Comment: @UlfR if you were not aiming for animation, then this would be the answer. It's totally OK. I've just thought the problem is the animate feature of the `toggle()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make it displayed as table. First set display table in your css stylesheet then hide it by using jquery, then apply the toggle.

css:

```
div{
    display: table;
}
```

jquery:

```
$('div').css('display','none');
$('button').on('click',function(){
$('div').toggle();
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3XEbK/)

Inspect it now and you should see the the div is displayed as table.

Comment: Your demo is wrong @"King King", you forgot to set table-cell on the cells. See [this modified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3XEbK/2/)

Comment: @UlfR the modified demo is also wrong, in fact it has not been modified. So this is the best answer I think. Please accept it, what are you waiting for?

Comment: Yep I inserted the wrong link, sorry, but its updated and working now.